# How to confirm the file getdata.php exist in given url

Tags: java, php

This is my code, currently it just can connect to the url. how to confirm the file is exist(gedata.php). (the url is not real, i change the real url for security reason)

```
URLConnection conn = new URL("http://testweb/trueweb.com.my/getdata.php").openConnection();
 conn.connect();
```

any idea folk?

EDIT ANSWERED (credit to Hanlet Escaño for providing code):

```
URLConnection conn = new URL("http://www.google.com.my").openConnection();
  conn.connect();  

  int code = ((java.net.HttpURLConnection)conn).getResponseCode();
   if (code == 404)
        {
        System.out.println("URL not exist");
        } 
   else{
       System.out.println("URL Exist!");
   }
```

Comment: Just remember that this will work only if `testweb` serwer is working and being able to return response code. If you will try to connect to non-existing/non-working server you will see `UnknownHostException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int code = ((java.net.HttpURLConnection)conn).getResponseCode();
```

Then check if the code is 404 you know your page did not exist:

```
if (code == 404)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the HTTP headers for a status code. You really only want to look for 200. 200 = page is ok and 404 is page not found